# Remove the letters between two patterns of strings in R

Tags: regex, r, string

How can I remove the letters between two specific patterns in R?

For instance

```
a= "a#g abcdefgtdkfef_jpg>pple"
```

I would like to remove all the letters between `#g` and `jpg>`

```
a1="apple"
```

I tried to find some function in `stringr` but I couldn't

Comment: You misspelled 'stringr'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding to the previous replies, if you work with a string that looks like `"a#g abcdefgtdkfef_jpg>pple ; #__something_else___jpg>"`, some of these methods will sub the whole string with an expression like `"#.*jpg>"`, and you will get an empty string as a result. To avoid that, you can use R regex `"#[^jpg>]+jpg>"` that will allow you to match the pattern more selectively.

Comment: `[^jpg>]+` does not mean *any text but a `jpg>` sequence. This is a misleading pattern, and should not be used.

Answer (score 21):

There's no need to load a package for this operation.  You can use the base R function `sub`.  It's used to match the first occurrence of a regular expression.

```
a <- "a#g abcdefgtdkfef_jpg>pple"
sub("#g.*jpg>", "", a)
# [1] "apple"
```

[Regular expression explained:](http://liveforfaith.com/re/explain.pl?re=%23g.*jpg%3E&.submit=Explain!&mode=SO&.cgifields=mode)

- `#g` matches `"#g"`
- `.*` matches any character except `\n` (zero or more times)
- `jpg>` matches `"jpg>"`

So here we're removing everything starting at `#g` up to and including `jpg>`

---

In regards to your comment

> I tried to find some function in stringR but I couldn't

It's actually spelled `stringr` (case-sensitive).  You could use `str_replace`.

```
library(stringr)
str_replace(a, "#g.*jpg>", "")
# [1] "apple"
```

Comment: For strict adherence to the request it would be `"#.*jpg>"`

Comment: Any insight into why anyone would prefer `stringr::str_replace()` to `sub()`?

Comment: @JoshO'Brien No, but I added it because OP mentioned they were looking in `stringr` and couldn't find a function for this.  I prefer base R for regex

Comment: Ah, yes. In that case, glad that you at least showed them they don't really need `stringr` for this!

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to add to Rich's answer because it does not work when multiple replacements need to be done in the same text.

If you want to remove multiple times in the same string you need to tweak the code a bit:

```
a <- "a#g abcdefgtdkfef_jpg>pple
or#g abcdefgtdkfef_jpg>ange
ma#g abcdefgtdkfef_jpg>ngo"

# Code to get the individual fruits
gsub("#g.*?jpg>", "", a)

# Output
# [1] "apple orange mango"
```

Comment: If you preferred `stringr` there is also `str_replace_all`.