# Remove characters between 1) opening and closing pattern and 2) if no closing pattern, opening pattern and end

Tags: r, regex

Have a solution to the problem using a chain of two `gsub` calls - out of curiosity, I wondered if there is a shorter regex for what I want to achieve. (using solution from [Remove the letters between two patterns of strings in R](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26682107/7941188))

I want to remove all characters either between the occurrence of a certain pattern, or - if there is no "closing pattern", between the "opening" pattern and the end.

```r
foostring <- c("First test *** no asterisks at the end", 
               "Second test *** asterisks in the middle *** something different",
               "Third test *** more than one asterisk *** something different *** second asterisk ***",
               "Fourth test *** asterisks followed by a special character ***_something different")

# desired output with chain of gsubs

gsub("\\*{3}.*$", "", gsub("\\*{3}.*?\\*{3}", "", foostring)) 
#> [1] "First test "                      "Second test  something different"
#> [3] "Third test  something different " "Fourth test _something different"
```

Comment: Maybe `gsub("\\*{3}.*?(?:\\*{3}|$)", "",  foostring)`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew If this comes from you, it kind of *must* be right :) I'll check it out. Thanks so much for the suggestion

Comment: See https://ideone.com/iwHxgy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```r
gsub("\\*{3}.*?(?:\\*{3}|$)", "",  foostring)
```

See the [R online demo](https://ideone.com/iwHxgy)

The TRE regex means:

- `\*{3}` - three asterisks
- `.*?` - any zero or more chars as few as possible
- `(?:\\*{3}|$)` - a non-capturing group matching

  - `\*{3}` - either three asterisks
  - `|` - or
  - `$`  - end of string.