# How to remove characters between space and specific character in R

Tags: r, regex, string

I have a question similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26682107/remove-the-letters-between-two-patterns-of-strings-in-r) but instead of having two specific characters to look between, I want to get the text between a space and a specific character. In my example, I have this string:

```
myString <- "This is my string I scraped from the web. I want to remove all instances of a picture. picture-file.jpg. The text continues here. picture-file2.jpg"
```

but if I were to do something like this: `str_remove_all(myString, " .*jpg)` I end up with

```
[1] "This"
```

I know that what's happening is R is finding the first instance of a space and removing everything between that space and ".jpg" but I want it to be the first space immediately before ".jpg". My final result I hope for looks like this:

```
[1] "This is my string I scraped from the web. I want to remove all instances of a picture. the text continues here.
```

NOTE: I know that a solution may arise which does what I want, but ends up putting two periods next to each other. I do not mind a solution like that because later in my analysis I am removing punctuation.

Comment: Use `str_remove_all(myString, "\\S*\\.jpg)` or `str_remove_all(myString, "\\s*\\S*\\.jpg)`

Comment: what is the difference between the lower and upper case S?

Comment: `\S` matches any non-whitespace character. `\s` matches whitespace chars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```r
str_remove_all(myString, "\\S*\\.jpg")
```

Or, if you also want to remove optional whitespace before the "word":

```r
str_remove_all(myString, "\\s*\\S*\\.jpg")
```

*Details*:

- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `\S*` - zero or more non-whitespaces
- `\.jpg` - `.jpg` substring.

To make it case insensitive, add `(?i)` at the pattern part: `"(?i)\\s*\\S*\\.jpg"`.

If you need to make sure there is no word char after `jpg`, add a word boundary: `"(?i)\\s*\\S*\\.jpg\\b"`